# CAPL program in CANanalyzer 7.0 tool

Tags: gcc

```
/*@@var:*/
variables
{

int a,b;
mstimer ramky;
}
/*@@end*/

/*@@startStart:Start:*/
on start
{ settimer (ramky,500);
}
/*@@end*/

/*@@timer:ramky:*/
on timer ramky
{

write("timer was started");
}
/*@@end*/

/*@@key:'a':*/
on key 'a'
{
write("hey u have pressed the key a");
a=5;
b=51;
check();
}
/*@@end*/

/*@@caplFunc:check():*///function
check ()
{
for(;a<=50;a++)
write("a=%d b=%d",a,b);
write("a=%d b=%d",a,b);
//again();

}
/*@@end*/

/*@@caplFunc:again():*///function
again ()
{
while(a==b)
write(" and b are same");
}
/*@@end*/
```

this is the program in executed in the `CANanlyzer 7.0` tool then my output was none and my pc was hanging so I want to know what will the reason for not giving the output?
Is there any problem with in the program?

Answer (score 0):

I see that CAPL script is not well establised.
Here you set the timer first and then you are not resetting again. The variables declared in On key event should be done on global decleration section because you are not passing the varaiables as arguments in function call. probably code stucks when check() function is invoked.